# How to initialize a data storage system

Tags: server, storage, esxi, san

I have an IBM EXP395 data storage system, it is connected to the HP manager, and connected via a multimode optical cable to san24b switches (fabric os 6.3.0b), and from them via a multimode optical cable connected to servers

esxi 6.5 is installed on the servers (so far without a cluster and without vcenter), a virtual machine with win server 2016 is open on one of them, I need each of the servers to see this disk space and be able to use it.